# HorizSync and VertRefresh for ASUS PG191

Tags: xorg, asus

It is hard to find correct values, cause Ubuntu didn't set them automatically. Maximum resolution which is caped at `800x600` is annoying.

UPD:

1. Video card: GeForce GTX 650 Ti
2. NVIDIA proprietary drivers version: 378.13

Comment: @Alban I don't understand your point. I don't think it's driver or video card issue, cause I had same problem with different configurations (don't remember).

Comment: @Alban Just try to find horizsync and verticalrefresh for this monitor :) I think answer can be useful for someone. I spent a few hours to find correct values. There is plenty of hardware that doesn't support hdmi.

Comment: It would be (or have been) interesting to see the output of `xrandr` *without* the changes to `xorg.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my monitor section, where you can see **correct** values that I use.
You should copy paste it in your `xorg.conf`. I don't remember where I found this, but it works.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
    HorizSync       29.0 - 68.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 75.0
    Modeline        "1280x1024" 108.000 1280 1328 1440 1688 1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
```

xrandr output:

```
user@user-pc ~ $ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      75.03 +  70.07    60.00  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1360x768      59.96    59.80  
   1280x1024     60.02* 
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x525       59.98  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
   512x384       70.07    60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       72.81    60.05  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: @Alban I self-answered my question to share knowledge :)

Comment: @Forester It's complete answer. Not ADDITIONAL INFORMATION for question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster this isn't additional information. It is the *new* `xorg.conf` the OP created which solves the issue.

Comment: @Inline as you can see, your answer is a bit confusing. Please edit it and explain what file you changed (presumably `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but maybe one of the files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`?) and what other actions you needed to take for this to work. That way, people will understand that it is indeed an answer and others will benefit from your knowledge (as it stands, this won't help anyone not familiar with the system since you don't explain what you did in detail).

Comment: @terdon Okey. I will do that tomorrow. If somebody can, please propose an edit, cause my English is bad :)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I would highly suggest you [edit] your answer to include *where* you got these values from, as right now it seems like they're being pulled from thin air. As such, this answer is useless for anyone that needs different values, because they still don't know how to get their own values. I'd also include information as to *where* you put the `Monitor` lines.